# Typo when creating a new environmental variable in terminal and now see -bash: exort: command not found in every terminal window

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

Beginner here with what I hope is a simple question!

I entered 'exort' rather than 'export' when creating a new environmental variable using the terminal and now every time I open a new terminal window I see the following:

```
$ -bash: exort: command not found
```

I have looked at the environmental variables saved to my bash profile (`~/.bash_profile`) and the one with the typo is on the penultimate line:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load 
RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export SEASON=winter
exort ANOTHERVAR=salut
export ANOTHERVAR=salut
```

I tried to run

```
$ unset ANOTHERVAR
```

but it didn't seem to remove ANOTHERVAR.

Would appreciate any suggestions on how I can remove ANOTHERVAR and delete this line from the terminal window.

Thank you very much

Comment: What's your question? You already got to the bottom of the problem, identified the erroneous line and (as it seems) even wrote a second one correcting it, what's the problem? You should just remove the `exort` line from the file and you're good to go.

Comment: when you say "bash profile" do you mean `~/.bash_profile`? If so, why did you create that file? Normally you'd add local environment variables to `~/.profile`, which will not be read if `~/.bash_profile` exists. If you don't mean `~/.bash_profile`, what file are you talking about?

Comment: Zanna, dessert: It _might_ be that the OP added the lines via `echo "export ANOTHERVAR=salut" >> ~/.bash_profile` (or whatever file) and now doesn't know how to remove them.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! Yes, @PerlDuck that is how I added the line.  I was just missing the last step of removing the line from the file which I've now corrected.

Comment: So which file was it? We're just curious.

Comment: I meant ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix typo `export` instead of `exort` in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
...
export ANOTHERVAR=salut
...
```

with your favorite text editor such as `gedit ~/.bashrc`.

Or you could use `sed` in this way:

```
sed -i 's/exort/export/' ~/.bashrc
```

- The option `-i` means make the changes in place within the file `~/.bashrc`.
- The command `s/` means substitute the first string with the second one; `/` is a delimiter.

Comment: @Serena If this answer solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.